# SQL SELECT and check column from second table

Tags: sql, join, select

I have two tables in my database. From the Table B i collect some data. I include by using JOIN the data from Table A. In this table there is a column user_id. The user id in table B is the the id from Table A. No i want to get all data from table A but without showing data if the table A id is in the table B column user_id available. I think the trick is the correct usage of JOIN but i need to check the whole column and not just one line.

SQL Query (which is probably not working)

```
SELECT * FROM tableB
JOIN tableA
ON tableB.user_id = tableA.id
WHERE tableB.user_id != tableA.id
```

Please see my example i have prepared in Excel:
[image: Database table example]

Comment: Thanks for asking question with such detail information. Desired output and dbms name would be even better to be mentioned.

Comment: true, next time i will add example expected output.

Comment: Thanks. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all the data from tableA where id is not available in tableB you don't need join rather you can use `not exists` or `not in`.

I would prefer `not exists`

Using `not exists`:

```
SELECT * from tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM tableB b
                    WHERE b.user_id = a.id
                 );
```

using `not in`:

```
SELECT * from tableA a
WHERE id not in (SELECT user_id FROM tableB );
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table TableA (id int, name varchar(50), lastname varchar(50));
 insert into TableA values(1,'john','smith');
 insert into TableA values(2,'Paul','smith');
 
 create table TableB (id int, user_id int, something varchar(50));
 insert into TableB values(1,2,'bla');
 insert into TableB values(2,3,'bla');
```

Query: (using not exists)

```
 SELECT * from tableA a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM tableB b
                     WHERE b.user_id = a.id
                  );
```

Output:

| id | name | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | smith |

Query: (using not in)

```
 SELECT * from tableA 
 WHERE id not in (SELECT user_id  FROM tableB );
```

Output:

| id | name | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | smith |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03dd831e33a4578cb01fb209e1785df8)*

Comment: 'not in' looks faster. Why you would prefer 'not exists'?

Comment: If there is any null value in user_id column of tableB then you will get wrong answer with `not in`. If there is no chance of having null in user_id column then definitely you can use not in.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you want.  You want `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB b JOIN
     tableA a
     ON b.user_id = a.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableA a2
                  WHERE b.user_id = a2.id
                 );
```

EDIT:

I wrote the above, but I didn't fully follow the `JOIN` conditions.  You either seem to want to join on `id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB b JOIN
     tableA a
     ON b.id = a.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableA a2
                  WHERE b.user_id = a2.id
                 );
```

Or no `JOIN` at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableA a2
                  WHERE b.user_id = a2.id
                 );
```

Comment: @MischaMustermann . . . I don't think so.  See the edit.

Comment: I recognized the mistake. The command 'NOT EXISTS' was hint enough to check the SQL reference ;)